# load custom configuration in sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I am building a Sinatra API and I have some custom configurations which needs to be used by the API.

For eg :

```
master:
  - role: 'production'
    node_ip: '192.168.1.1'
    notify: 'abc@gmail.com'
  - role: 'production'
    node_ip: '192.168.1.2'
    notify: 'def@gmail.com' 
  development:
    role: 'production'
    node_ip: '192.168.1.2'
    notify: 'def@gmail.com'
```

So I need use these configuation in my app. Right now I have put it in yml files and loading it and using it in my app. Is there any better way to do achieve the same without using yaml.

Comment: Just use a ruby file?

Comment: YAML is a good choice for this. But your YAML looks funny.....